# How to fix Worker Pool Deadlock

Tags: go

I wrote a pool of workers, where the job is to receive an integer and return that number converted to string. However I faced a `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!` error. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

https://play.golang.org/p/U814C2rV5na

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate your issue and fix it by using a pointer to `master` instead of a normal variable.

Basically just change your `NewWorker()` method  to this:

```
func (m *Master) NewWorker() {
    m.Workers = append(m.Workers, Worker{})
}
```

Here's the output the program prints after the change:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
.
.
.
```

### Reason:

Everytime you called `NewWorker()` method, you weren't appending a `worker` to the same master object. That's why the slice never got populated with 3 workers, as should've been the case.

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Y-kcsCI08tu)